# Convert yahoofinancials multidimensional dictionary output to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm creating a stock screener based on fundamental metrics using yahoofinancials module.

Below code gives output in multidimensional dictionary format that I'm not able to convert into dataframe format for further analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

ticker = 'RELIANCE.NS'
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
income_statement_data_qt = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('quarterly', 'income')
income_statement_data_qt
```

Output:
[image]

Ideally, I'd like to have data in this format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to iterate over the dictionaries from that particular `ticker` and use Pandas [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the data along the columns axis (`axis=1`). Then, use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to convert the index to a column with the desired name. Create a new column with the `ticker` name at the first position using [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

ticker = 'RELIANCE.NS'
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
income_statement_data_qt = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('quarterly', 'income')

dict_list = income_statement_data_qt['incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly'][ticker]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in dict_list], axis=1)
df = df.rename_axis('incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly').reset_index()
df.insert(0, 'ticker', ticker)
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
         ticker    incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly  ...    2021-03-31    2020-12-31
0   RELIANCE.NS                      costOfRevenue  ...  1.034690e+12  7.224900e+11
1   RELIANCE.NS             discontinuedOperations  ...           NaN           NaN
2   RELIANCE.NS                               ebit  ...  1.571800e+11  1.490100e+11
3   RELIANCE.NS          effectOfAccountingCharges  ...           NaN           NaN
...
...
18  RELIANCE.NS       sellingGeneralAdministrative  ...  3.976000e+10  4.244000e+10
19  RELIANCE.NS             totalOperatingExpenses  ...  1.338570e+12  1.029590e+12
20  RELIANCE.NS         totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet  ... -1.330000e+09  2.020000e+09
21  RELIANCE.NS                       totalRevenue  ...  1.495750e+12  1.178600e+12

[22 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Got it. Works perfectly!

Comment: I've done both.